# MySQL rank query. Get the position of a specific member

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table on my DataBase:
**TimeRank(user-id, name, time)**

I would like to order the table by time and get the position of an specific ID on the table, for example:

*The user nº 68 is on the 3rd position.*

I only need to do a query that returns the position of the user.

MySQL don't have the function row_number, so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT x.user-id, 
       x.name,
       x.time,
       x.position
  FROM (SELECT t.user-id,
               t.name,
               t.time,
               @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position
          FROM TABLE TimeRank t
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
          ORDER BY t.time) x
 WHERE x.user-id = 123
```

Alternative:

```
SELECT user-id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TimeRank WHERE time <= (SELECT time FROM TimeRank WHERE user-id = 123)) AS position,
       time,
       name
FROM TimeRank
WHERE user-id = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a position column with a variable

```
set @pos=0;

select pos,user_id
from (select @pos:=@pos+1 pos,user_id from TimeRank order by time) s
where user_id=68;
```

If indexing is a concern, you can add a column to your table and update it with

```
set @pos=0;

update TimeRank set position=(@pos:=@pos+1) order by time;
```