# Calculating rank not working - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB Table `user_points` which contains user's points and I am trying to calculate ranking based on points. It is working fine for all users except users having 1 point.

If user have 1 point **it is showing it's rank as 0** but **it should display it's rank as last or in last numbers** like: 12083 etc.

Higher points are, ranking should be higher as well. For example:

> 1000 points = rank 1
>
> 1 point = rank 1223

Following is the query.

```
SELECT id, mobileNo, points, 
       FIND_IN_SET( points, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( points ORDER BY points DESC ) 
                             FROM users_points )) AS rank 
FROM users_points 
WHERE mobileNo = '03214701777'
```

What should I change to fix it?

Comment: Define "working fine" vs. "not working fine".  What is the data?  What is the result?  What is the desired result?

Comment: What's the breakpoints for each rank? Why is rank 1223 exactly 1 point and rank 1 exactly 1000 points?

Comment: What happen if two users have the same points? My guess is lot of user have 1 points so the order of those is random

Comment: @Qirel not exactly, that's just an example.

Comment: @David Updated the question.

Comment: So you are asking how one would query to get where you are on the "rank-ladder", based on how many points you have? The one with most points is rank 1, the one with least points is last, sorted as such?

Comment: @Qirel exactly. Sorry for unclear question. i was panicked.

Comment: look at the answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select

Comment: answer there is wrong for this question - if 2 entities have the same points/ordercount they will get different rankings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id, a.mobileNo, a.points, 
   IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) AS rank
    FROM users_points b
    WHERE b.points<a.points), 0)+1 as rank
FROM user_points a
WHERE a.mobileNo  = '03214701777'
```

Seems to be what you are looking for. While it is still very innefficient it is better than your approach using FIND_IN_SET(). If you really want to use FIND_IN_SET() then you need to pad the scores to a consistent width and divide by the width+1 to get the rank.

Comment: I think it is working fine to some extent. But it is showing rank in reverse order. 

`Higher points (100) = Higher Rank (230)` but it should be `higher points (100) = lower rank (1)`.

Comment: The `nullif()` is superfluous.

Comment: Changing `<` to `>` worked perfectly for me :) thanks.