# SQL Function to Replace specific text with Count

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm looking for a function to get result in below format:

Input:

```
| name     |
| -------- |
| DFHG     |
| DRTYFGJN |
| FGH      |
| FGH      |
| NBHFGD   |
| OIUKJH   |
| RTFHGJ   |
| TDHG     |
```

Desired output:

```
| id  | name     |
| --- | -------- |
| 1   | DFHG     |
| 2   | DRTYFGJN |
| 3   | FGH      |
| 4   | FGH      |
| 5   | NBHFGD   |
| 6   | OIUKJH   |
| 7   | RTFHGJ   |
| 8   | TDHG     |
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: what is the difference between input and output?Do you want to have row number in output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - Get row number on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select)

Comment: It seems odd to call this an 'id'

Answer (score 2):

First option is by using variable

```
set @rank=0;

select
    @rank:=@rank+1 as id,
    name
from myTable
order by 
    name;
```

Second option is by using `row_number()`, only if you are using MySQL 8.0.

```
select 
    row_number() over (order by name) as id,
    name
from myTable;
```

Comment: Your first query needs an `ORDER BY` clause otherwise it could produce a different result every time it is run.

Comment: I rather think that if the output doesn't match the desired result, then something's wrong somewhere

Comment: The variables in the first query are not guaranteed to follow the `order by`.