# MySQL Get multple rows for a single row in db

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a select query

```
select id from tags
```

Which returns data like

```
id
--
1
2
```

I want to get data with a sequence number as shown below

```
id seq
-- ---
1  1
1  2
1  3
1  4
1  5
2  1
2  2
2  3
2  4
2  5
```

How can I achieve this in mysql

Comment: `select id,seq from tags` maybe? you are not showing the structure of your table.. so we need to guess? 
Please take the [tour]. See also [ask] and in your Question add a [mre]

Comment: Sequence is not present in tag table, lets assume that tag table only has one colum named tag_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id, seq
from tags
cross join (
    select 1 seq union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
) seqs
order by id, seq
```

Or

```
with recursive seqs as (
    select 1 seq
    union all
    select seq+1
    from seqs
    where seq < 5
)
select id, seq
from tags
cross join seqs  
order by id, seq
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an incremental variable as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2520377/2984776);

In your case, the query should be like this:

```
SET @rowcount=0;
SELECT id, @rowcount:=@rowcount+1 as seq from tags;
```