# sql output as a ranking

Tags: sql, mysql, analytics, ranking, rank

If I have a table of random values in a sql table, how can I export and display them as a raking rather than the absolute value... for example.. if the three values are 30 85 and 90 how do i get 30 do display as 1 or 1st, 85 as 2 or 2nd etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to generate ranks in MYSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431053/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-ranks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have analytic function support (ROW_NUMBER, RANK, DENSE_RANK), which is generally what you'd use for requirements like these.

Use:

```
  SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS ranking
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
    JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
ORDER BY t.value
```

Example:

```
  SELECT x.num,
         @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS ranking
    FROM (SELECT 30 AS num
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 85
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 90) x
    JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
ORDER BY x.num
```

You could use:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM YOUR_TABLE b
         WHERE b.value <= a.value) AS ranking
  FROM YOUR_TABLE a
```

...but duplicates would have the same ranking value.  And you have to make sure the value comparison is in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
set @i = 0;
select myValue,
        @i:=@i+1 as Ranking
from myTable 
order by myValue ASC
```

Comment: You probably want an `ORDER BY myValue ASC` in there.