# show row number in select query

Tags: mysql, sql

what is the problem with this query? it shows null in rowno column.

```
SELECT @rowno:=@rowno+1 `rn`,`id`, `title`, `topic` 
FROM stories,(SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
WHERE newstype='2';
```

i run it in 'MySQL Query browser'

thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to generate ranks in MYSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431053/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-ranks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the increment you are using `rowno` but in the initial assignment you are using `rownum`

Answer (score 8):

You have a few problems there:

- You need to initialise `@rowno` by adding `set @rowno = 0` before the query.
- You're missing an `as` in `@rowno:=@rowno+1 rn`.
- The `(SELECT @rownum:=0) r` is superfluous, unless you meant this to be the initialisation for `@rowno` in which case you misspelt it.

This should work:

```
SET @rowno = 0;
SELECT @rowno:=@rowno+1 as `rn`, `id`, `title`, `topic` 
FROM stories 
WHERE newstype='2';
```

Comment: this solution does not work if records are ordered by some other field