# MySql - Getting rowid / order in a complex query

Tags: mysql, sql

Working on a project with students/grades/etc, I need to update the top 3 students every once in a while. I came up with the query below. However, I am having trouble getting their rank/order. I know how to do that in a simple query, but in a more complex one, it is not working.
I am getting all of the other columns correctly, and, with all the methods I tried to get the order by, I sometimes got 0 (like the current state of the code), sometimes values that are just wrong (1, 11, 10), etc.

NOTE: I have checked various questions (including the question below), but I just couldn't figure out how to place them in my query.

[What is the best way to generate ranks in MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431053/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-ranks-in-mysql)

**Summary:** 

GOAL:
 - Get sum of each students' marks from `marks`, divide that on the number of entries in the table (again `marks`). Students are from a given grade.
 - Use `sum(mark)` to rank these students.
 - Get the top three.
 - Place the top three students from that grade in the `TopStudents` table, with their average marks (as `sum`) and their id's.

TABLES:

**Students table** contains info about student including id:

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int   (20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        |varchar(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Marks Table**  has marks of each student on each exam

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          |int    (20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| idStudent   |int    (20) unsigned | NO   | FOR | NULL    |                |
| mark        |tinyInt (3) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| idExam      |int    (20) unsigned | NO   | FOR | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Grade Table**  has grade id and name:

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int   (20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        |varchar(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Class Table**  classes for each grade. References table

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int   (20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        |varchar(20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| idGrade     |  int  (20) unsigned | NO   | FOR | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and finally, the infamous  **TopStudents Table** .

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int   (20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| idStudent   | int   (20) unsigned | NO   | FOR | NULL    |                |
|  sumMarks   | int   (20) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
|  rank       |tinyInt (1) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
|  date       |date     unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

ATTEMPTS:
 **Attempt 1**: ERROR: all ranks are 0

```
INSERT INTO topStudents(`date`, idStudent, `sum`, `order`)
SELECT
    '2018-10-10' AS DATE,
    student.id AS idStudent,
    AVG(marks.mark)
    @n = @n + 1 AS `order`
FROM
    marks
INNER JOIN student ON student.id = marks.idStudent
INNER JOIN class ON class.id = marks.idClass
INNER JOIN grade ON class.idGrade = grade.id
WHERE
    grade.id = 2
GROUP BY
    marks.idStudent
ORDER BY
    SUM(mark)
DESC
LIMIT 3
```

**Attempt 2**: ranks returned: 1, 11, 10

```
SET @n := 0;


INSERT INTO topStudents(`date`, idStudent, `sum`, `rank`)
SELECT
    '2018-10-10' AS DATE,
    tbl.idStudent AS idStudent,
    AVG(tbl.mark) AS `sum`,

    rnk AS `rank`
FROM (SELECT student.id AS idStudent, SUM(mark) AS mark FROM
    marks
INNER JOIN student ON student.id = marks.idStudent
INNER JOIN class ON class.id = marks.idClass
INNER JOIN grade ON class.idGrade = grade.id
WHERE
    grade.id = 2
GROUP BY
    marks.idStudent
ORDER BY
    SUM(mark)
DESC
LIMIT 3) AS tbl, (SELECT @n = @n + 1) AS rnk
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry I edited accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In more recent versions of MySQL, you need to use a derived table for the ordering, before assigning the ranks:

```
INSERT INTO topStudents (`date`, idStudent, `sum`, `order`)
    SELECT date, idStudent, `sum`, (@n := @n + 1) AS `order`
    FROM (SELECT '2018-10-10' AS DATE, s.id AS idStudent,
                 SUM(m.mark) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM marks m2 WHERE m2.idStudent = m.idStudent) AS `sum`    
          FROM marks m JOIN
               student s
               ON s.id = m.idStudent JOIN
               class c
               ON c.id = m.idClass JOIN
               grade g
               ON c.idGrade = g.id
          WHERE g.id = 2
          GROUP BY m.idStudent
          ORDER BY SUM(mark) DESC
          LIMIT 3
         ) sm CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT @n := 0) params;
```

I am almost certain that the calculation for `sum` is incorrect, and that you really intend `avg(mark)`.  However, this is the logic you have in your question.

Comment: For simplicity's sake, I trimmed some of the query, which led to that `sum` mistake. In reality I need to divide it by other parameters which are not shown in my question, so I thought this will do. Anywho, your query returned results similar to one of my test (I tried so many I can't remember) : order (ranks) where all 0.

Comment: @skullz . . . There was a typo -- the assignment needs to use `:=`, not `=`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Many thanks